# auto login while testing (and assigning a particular role to a testing user)

Tags: c#, security, forms-authentication, membership-provider, roleprovider

I found this: [ASP.NET forms authentication - auto login with a test account while debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071095/asp-net-forms-authentication-auto-login-with-a-test-account-while-debugging) - which would get me half the way there.

What would be the recommended approach to attach roles to the signed on user (for testing different permissions).  I have a custom membership / role providers - so I guess I could override the role providers while in testing / debugging mode to grab a test role out of webconfig app settings etc. - but I don't want to be over thinking it where there may be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create several different testusers, each with their appropriate roles and determine which user to auto-login from an entry in the webconfig?

Comment: quicker to create seven users for seven roles than seven hours of testing a customized role provider.  You get a green checkmark!